# If statement in a nested loop logic

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, logic

I am struggling with some logic. I have a nested for loop with an if statement inside.

```
foreach(object in list)
 foreach(otherObject in otherList)
  if(object.name == otherObject.name)
   foo();
   break;
  else
   bar();
```

This will do bar() everytime the if statement is false. How can I do bar() only if foo() is never done? Apologies if this a repeated question, which it probably is...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly your problem is that the break statement only leaves the inner, but not the outer loop. This is usually one of the rare cases in which a goto out of the neested loop structure is in place.

Comment: @nv3 Thanks for this. While this wasn't the issue I was asking about, I wasn't aware of the goto functionality. This will also help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a flag:

```cs
did_foo = false;

foreach(object in list)
 foreach(otherObject in otherList)
  if(object.name == otherObject.name)
   foo();
   did_foo = true;
   break;

if (!did_foo)
  bar();
```